# Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is: out of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, out-of-memory

Here is my code

```
- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData  {
    //   NSLog( @"\n*****Save image to SQLite*****\n" );
    sqlite3 *sqlite3DatabaseObject;
    sqlite3_stmt* sqlite3Statement;
    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

    const char* sqlite3Query = "INSERT INTO ABCD (image) VALUES (?)";

        BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, -1, sqlite3Query);
        if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_stmt* sqlite3Statement;

            BOOL sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
            if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK ) {


                sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);


            }
        }
        else NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject) );

        sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);
    }
```

and its throwing an error as:

> SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  out of memory

Could anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

Now that I've fixed the `sqlite3_open_v2` problems and a few of the other issues identified below, I'm now receiving a different error message:

> SaveBody: Prepare failure: no such table: ABCD

This is my revised code:

```
- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData  {
    //   NSLog( @"\n*****Save image to SQLite*****\n" );
    sqlite3 *sqlite3DatabaseObject;
    sqlite3_stmt* sqlite3Statement;
    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"picdb.sqlite"];

    const char* sqlite3Query = "INSERT INTO ABCD (image) VALUES (?)";
    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    // int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, -1, sqlite3Query);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt* sqlite3Statement;
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
        if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK ) {

            sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else
        {
        NSLog(@"Prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject));
        }
    }
    else NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject) );

    sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);
}
```

Comment: Do not change the question so that existing answers become invalid.

Comment: okay,sorry I wasn't aware of this, I am new to StackOverflow.Will be careful hereafter.

Comment: By the way, the `else` clause to your `sqlite3_open_v2` check is still using `sqlite3_errmsg`. You should not try to use `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_open_v2` failed. For pretty much any other call, it's fine, but not for open failures.

Comment: Actually in sqlite3_prepare_v2 I am getting 1 as status code .

Comment: issue resolved here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339680/image-not-store-in-sqlite/43342534#43342534

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues:

1. The log statement says that it's logging `sqlite3_prepare_v2` errors, but it's not. It's logging `sqlite3_open_v2` errors.
2. The `sqlite3_open_v2` is failing because:

   - the third parameter is not valid (it should be just what flags you need, e.g. `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` or whatever); and
   - you're providing a pointer to `sqlite3Query` for the last parameter, but that's not what that fourth parameter is for.

   For more information, see the [documentation for `sqlite3_open_v2`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).
3. The misleading "out of memory" error occurs because `sqlite3_errmsg` was not passed a valid database pointer. Obviously, since the open failed, you don't have a valid database pointer and you therefore cannot use `sqlite3_errmsg` with open failures. Just log the `openDatabaseResult` value.
4. Note, these `sqlite3_xxx` functions do not return `BOOL`. They return `int`. In the case of `sqlite3_open_v2`, examining the return value is the only way to diagnose what's going on, and if you use `BOOL`, you can lose important numeric values.

Comment: ok, now please check my updated code.Now I am facing issue in sqlite3_prepare_v2 method , it says my table doesn't exist.

Comment: So, that means that the table doesn't exist. That can happen if the database didn't exist and `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` says "create a blank database if it is not found". So, if there's really a blank database, get rid of it. And then figure out where the database with the actual table is.

Comment: Personally, when using a pre-built database, I will see if database exists in Documents folder (or I'll check the version of the database), if not, copy it from bundle to Documents folder, and then always open the database with `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` only (not `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`). It avoids SQLite from ever creating blank database on me. Note, once you have blank database, you'll probably want to uninstall the app, and then reinstall, to make sure that any blank databases are removed.

Comment: I have done that,but yet I am facing the same issue in sqlite3_prepare_v2.Please check my updated code.

Comment: It's not the same issue. It's a different error. So you removed `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`? And you completely removed app from your device/simulator and tried again? How was this database created? How did it get to the Documents folder?

Comment: issue resolved here is the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339680/image-not-store-in-sqlite/43342534#43342534