# Image not store in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage

I made one demo which stores an Image to the database. Currently I am not getting any error but my image is not store in sqlite database.
Please see the below code and tell me where is my mistake.

**DBManager class**

```
sqlite3 *sqlite3DatabaseObject;
sqlite3_stmt* sqlite3Statement;
-(void)database
{

    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO) {
        const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqlite3DatabaseObject)== SQLITE_OK) {
            char * errorMessage;
            const char *sqlite3Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PICTURES (PHOTO BLOB)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage)!= SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"failed = %@",sqlite3DatabaseObject);
            }
            sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"failed to create database");
        }
    }
}
- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData  {

    NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"informationdb" ofType:@"sql"];

    const char* sqlite3Query = "INSERT INTO PICTURES (PHOTO) VALUES (?)";
    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
        if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK ) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);

    }
    else NSLog( @"Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject) );
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
}
```

**ViewController class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DBManager * dbmClass = [[DBManager alloc]init];
    [dbmClass database];

    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(uploadOrCapture)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {
    DBManager*dbmClass = [[DBManager alloc]init];
    NSData *imageInData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgView.image);
    [dbmClass SaveImagesToSql:imageInData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am not able to find out the issue. It successfully executes all the code but when I download the database from device and checked, there is no image data stored.

Thanks in advance.
Mihir.

Comment: suggestion : store image to local directory and save directory path into sqlite db.

Comment: can you have any tutorials links for that?

Comment: You can save your image in document directory and store the path of the image in database.

Comment: @MihirOza when you call btnSave that time you got imagedata?

Comment: yes @IOS_DEV I am getting

Comment: @MihirOza if possible than send me demo i will check it.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/ozamihir1990/sqliteDemo

Comment: @MihirOza ok i will check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace this function to my code because you got wrong database path

```
- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData  {

    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];

    const char* sqlite3Query = "INSERT INTO PICTURES (PHOTO) VALUES (?)";
    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
        if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK ) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);

    }
    else NSLog( @"Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject) );
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
}
```

here this is database screenshot

[image]

Don't drag to database in your project.if any problem than tell me

Answer (score 0):

Here How I do modify as per your use.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgView.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMyyyyhhmmss_SSS_a";
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];

NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%@",currentTime];

NSString *saveFilePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName,@"png"];  //Store saveFilePath string to your database

NSString *localFilePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFilePath];

[imageData writeToFile:localFilePath1 atomically:YES];
```

Hope it helps you.