# Image not retrieving from sql database in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

Hello I have been trying to retrieve image from sql database named informationdb.sql but I am not able to,could anyone help with that.Here is my code

```
- (NSData*) LoadImagesFromSql
{
    NSData* data = nil;
    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];

    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
         const char* sqlite3Query = "SELECT PHOTO FROM PICTURES";
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
    if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        const char *myData = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1);
        int myDataSize = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlite3Statement, 1);
        data = [NSData dataWithBytes:myData length:myDataSize];
        sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);
    }
         sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
    return data;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Simple questions: Do you pass the two `if` test? What's wrong exactly with your code? Also, please name your method starting with a lower case.

Comment: @Simeryn Denis in data you got any return value or not

Comment: @simeryn please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339680/image-not-store-in-sqlite?noredirect=1#comment73742927_43339680

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image not store in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339680/image-not-store-in-sqlite)

Comment: yes the if test was successful but "myData" is showing NULL.

Comment: @shahrukhshikalgar both quetion is different

Comment: @SimerynDenis ok wait i will check code

Comment: @SimerynDenis you want to display image in tableview or single imageview?

Comment: @IOS_DEV  It is an imageView.

Comment: @IOS_DEV and i didn't get any return value.

Comment: @SimerynDenis wait 15-20 min i will check your code

Comment: @IOS_DEV ok no problem

Comment: @SimerynDenis in your code if image store multiple than you need to change your database because in your database Pictures table only one field.and in LoadImagesFromSql() you got multiple image data

Comment: @IOS_DEV could you please tell what should i change in my code?

Comment: @SimerynDenis wait i will working in your code in create,insert,and display image function

Comment: @IOS_DEV thanks alot.

Comment: @SimerynDenis your demo is completed

Comment: @SimerynDenis tomorrow i will give update demo

Comment: @IOS_DEV ok no issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it by this:

```
- (NSData*) LoadImagesFromSql
{
    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];

    NSData* data = nil;
    //  int i=0;

    NSString* sqlite3Query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT PHOTO FROM PICTURES "];

    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, [sqlite3Query UTF8String], -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
        if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK )
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                const char *myData = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlite3Statement, 0);
                int myDataSize = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlite3Statement, 0);
                data = [NSData dataWithBytes:myData length:myDataSize];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
    return data;

}
```

and updated viewWillAppear as :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    dbmClass = [[DBManager alloc]init];
    if (imgPic.image != nil) {
        imgPic.image = nil;
    }
    imgPic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[dbmClass LoadImagesFromSql]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dbmClass LoadImagesFromSql]);


}
```

Comment: in your code try to save 2 or more image than check.you does not get image in imageview

Comment: No it works i tried saving 2 images it works perfectly.The method every time gets the last image which I upload in the database.

Answer (score 2):

first delete database in document directory than change all three method to my code

```
-(void)database
{

    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];
    NSLog(@"database path=%@",databasePath);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO) {
        const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqlite3DatabaseObject)== SQLITE_OK) {
            char * errorMessage;
            const char *sqlite3Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  PICTURES (PHOTO BLOB,Id integer PRIMARY KEY)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage)!= SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"failed = %@",sqlite3DatabaseObject);
            }
            sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"failed to create database");
        }
    }
}



- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData  {

    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];
    NSLog(@"database path=%@",databasePath);
    const char* sqlite3Query = "INSERT INTO PICTURES (PHOTO) VALUES (?)";
    int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3DatabaseObject, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        int sqlite3Prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DatabaseObject, sqlite3Query, -1, &sqlite3Statement, NULL);
        if( sqlite3Prepare == SQLITE_OK ) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3Statement, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(sqlite3Statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3Statement);

    }
    else NSLog( @"Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3DatabaseObject) );
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DatabaseObject);
}


- (NSData*)LoadImagesFromSql
{
    NSData* data = nil;
    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"informationdb.sql"]];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
    sqlite3 *db;
    int i = 1;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT PHOTO FROM PICTURES WHERE Id = %d",i];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStmt, 0);
                data = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStmt, 0) length:length];

                NSLog(@"Length : %lu", (unsigned long)[data length]);

//                if(imageData == nil)
//                    NSLog(@"No image found.");
//                else
//                    imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: @Simeryn Denis check my answer

Comment: it says table doesn't exist.

Comment: no buddy still it's not working.I deleted these 3 methods and replace with your code. It's SAYING **Error is: no such table: PICTURES**

Comment: @SimerynDenis debug create table function and check PICTURES table create or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141502/discussion-between-ios-dev-and-simeryn-denis).